# Prioritization data from data frame with dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, dictionary

I have a problem with my db, here is a sample frame that I am working on which describes number of toys (Qty) that I need to relocate to specific factory (To) and number of them which already is in other factories (A,B,C,D,E,F,G):

[image]

And I have created a dictionary which prioritize the destinations between this factories in format

'to': ['first choice', 'second choice'...]:

```
d = {'A': ['F', 'E', 'D', 'B'],
     'B': ['E', 'F'],
     'C': ['A', 'B'],
     'D': ['F', 'C', 'E', 'B', 'A'],
     'E': ['F', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A'],
     'F': ['F', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A'],
     'G': ['F', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'A']}
```

Now I wanted to pick toys from factory basing on my priority dict and create a new column which will show name of the factory.\

E.g. if I look at the toy with id 3 I want 20 of them to the factory A and as we can see there is a lack of them in factory F so I want to take 2 of them from factory F and rest (18) from the next one from my dictionary so from factory E.

Simple output:

[image]

Here is this tables in text to copy it to your excel/txt files.

```
ID  To  Qty A   B   C   D   E   F   G
1   A   6   0   0   0   0   0   302 0
2   A   4   0   625 0   0   357 0   0
3   A   20  0   0   0   318 154 2   0
4   B   12  0   0   0   0   0   473 0
5   C   13  0   0   0   0   0   6713 0
6   A   3   0   0   0   0   0   37  0
7   A   2   0   0   0   0   0   105 0
8   D   51  0   0   0   0   0   6782 0
9   B   2   0   0   0   0   0   946 0
```

EDIT:

```
ID           To      Qty     Comment       A    B     C    D    E     F    G
140071984011  F       2         Auto       0    9     6   18    5     0    9
8996619265029 D      84         Auto       0    0     0    0    0   139    0
8996619265029 E      18         Auto       0    0     0    0    0   139    0
8996619265029 G      10         Auto       0    0     0    0    0   139    0
8996619265029 A      17         Auto       0    0     0    0    0   139    0
8996619265029 C       2         Auto       0    0     0    0    0   139    0
```

I used the code from the answer but I've added an extra column named comment, and after that the code stop working properly, the output is like that:

```
out = (
    df.melt(['ID', 'To', 'Qty','Comment'], var_name='From', value_name='Stock')
        .set_index(['To', 'From']).query('Stock != 0')
        .assign(Priority=lambda x: x.index.map(pri))
        .sort_values(['ID', 'Priority'])
)
```

After that part of the code I've got:

```
               ID           Qty       Comment  Stock  Priority
store To                                                  
F     D     140071984011     2         Auto     18       0.0
      E     140071984011     2         Auto      5       1.0
      B     140071984011     2         Auto      9       NaN
      C     140071984011     2         Auto      6       NaN
      G     140071984011     2         Auto      9       NaN                                                  
D     F    8996619265029    84         Auto    139       0.0
E     F    8996619265029    18         Auto    139       0.0
G     F    8996619265029    10         Auto    139       0.0
A     F    8996619265029    17         Auto    139       0.0
C     F    8996619265029     2         Auto    139       1.0
```

But from the previous table we can see that only F factory need that toy with ID = 140071984011 in the number of 2 which we can take from factory C as it is in prioritization dict. In the second ID there is also a bugg, because after the second part of the code it returns only first row.

```
def update_qty(df):
    qty = df['Qty'] - df['Stock'].cumsum()
    return pd.Series(np.where(qty > 0, df['Stock'], df['Stock'] + qty),
                     index=df.index, name='Qty')

out = (
    out.assign(Stock=out['Stock'].mask(out['Priority'].isna()))
        .groupby('ID').apply(update_qty).reset_index().query('Qty.gt(0) | Qty.isna()')
)
```

And the results are:

```
    PNO       To    From  Qty
140071984011    F     D  2.0
140071984011    F     B  NaN
140071984011    F     C  NaN
140071984011    F     G  NaN
8996619265029   D     F  84.0
```

Comment: I edited your post and fixed `SyntaxError`. Avoid to use builtin as variable names.

Comment: @Ulewsky your priorities are too ambiguous and cyclic, example `A->B->E->F->A`. In the case where you need to get from A/B/E/F, which one would you chose? Or maybe better explain what the dictionary actually means

Comment: @mozway It means that if there are enough toys in factory A it should take them from there, if there are not enough toys in factory A it should take the rest from factory B, then from E ect. If there will be such situation that there are toys in factory C which is not included in dictionary it should print "not_avaliable"

Comment: I get the same quantity but I'm not sure to fully understand the question :) Can you check it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) The idea is to flat your dataframe, remove all factories with no stock and sort rows by priority. (2) For each `ID`, decrease the quantity until it reaches 0:

```
pri = {(k, v): i for k, l in d.items() for i, v in enumerate(l)}

out = (
    df.melt(['ID', 'To', 'Qty'], var_name='From', value_name='Stock')
      .set_index(['To', 'From']).query('Stock != 0')
      .assign(Priority=lambda x: x.index.map(pri))
      .sort_values(['ID', 'Priority'])
)
```

1. At this point your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> out
         ID  Qty  Stock  Priority
To From                          
A  F      1    6    302       0.0
   E      2    4    357       1.0
   B      2    4    625       3.0
   F      3   20      2       0.0  # take 2, remain 18
   E      3   20    154       1.0  # take 18, remain 0
   D      3   20    318       2.0  # don't use it
B  F      4   12    473       1.0
C  F      5   13   6713       NaN
A  F      6    3     37       0.0
   F      7    2    105       0.0
D  F      8   51   6782       0.0
B  F      9    2    946       1.0
```

2. Update quantity for each stock by priority:

```
def update_qty(df):
    qty = df['Qty'] - df['Stock'].cumsum()
    return pd.Series(np.where(qty > 0, df['Stock'], df['Stock'] + qty), 
                     index=df.index, name='Qty')

out = (
    out.assign(Stock=out['Stock'].mask(out['Priority'].isna()))
       .groupby('ID').apply(update_qty).reset_index().query('Qty.gt(0) | Qty.isna()')
)
```

Final output:

```
>>> out
    ID To From   Qty
0    1  A    F   6.0
1    2  A    E   4.0
3    3  A    F   2.0  # taken 2
4    3  A    E  18.0  # taken 18
6    4  B    F  12.0
7    5  C    F   NaN
8    6  A    F   3.0
9    7  A    F   2.0
10   8  D    F  51.0
11   9  B    F   2.0
```

Comment: Hi again, I wanted to add one more column and I figured out that there is some problem in the results, I will edit the post and maybe you could try to help me fixing it